# How does Async/await work and why does it not work here

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to understand how async/await works, all I want to do is have it wait until the value is returned. However, I could not get it to do so with callbacks nor promises nor `async/await`. What am I doing wrong, and why does `async/await` not work as I expect it to? (wait with running other code until this promise is resolved)

Many questions like this one link to "introduction pages". I've read them all, I understand what they do, I just don't know how to properly write them out, as I believe I did everything correctly, I'm just missing something
`console.log("xcdcxcxcxccxvccvffdgfcd")`;

```js
thing();
async function thing() {
    let c = await otherthing();
    console.log("dfasfadsfdasasdfa" + c)
}

async function otherthing() {
    await setTimeout(function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let f = "rerewwqfewfasgsadf"
            return resolve(f);
        })
    }, 3000);
}
```

`console.log` is supposed to wait until the promised value `c` is returned, however, it does not seem to work. Why?

Comment: Because `setTimeout` doesn't return a Promise

Comment: `otherthing` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async/await works with functions that return promises. Your `otherthing` function doesn't return anything.

You can fix the code by returning the promise you are instantiating, like this:

```js
    thing();

    async function thing() {
        let c = await otherthing();
        console.log("dfasfadsfdasasdfa" + c)
    }

    function otherthing() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                let f = "rerewwqfewfasgsadf"
                resolve(f);
            }, 3000)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You must `return` the `new Promise` from the `otherthing` function, not from the `setTimeout` callback. You are supposed to construct the promise, in its executor callback start the asynchronous action (`setTimeout`) and then asynchronously `resolve()` or `reject()` the promise.

```
function otherthing() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      let f = "rerewwqfewfasgsadf"
      resolve(f);
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

You don't need any `async`/`await` here for the function that is essentially only a promise wrapper around `setTimeout`. See also [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572).

Answer (score 2):

You should move `setTimeout` inside `Promise` body and there do `resolve(f)`

```
function otherthing() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let f = "rerewwqfewfasgsadf"
            resolve(f);
         }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`async function otherthing` has no `return` statement, so it will always return a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

`await setTimeout(...)` doesn't make any sense. You can only `await` a promise, and `setTimeout` does not return a promise.

---

You need to explicitly:

- create a `new Promise()` inside `otherthing`
- `resolve()` it with the desired value inside the callback function you pass to `setTimeout`
- `return` the promise from `otherthing`

Don't create a promise inside the callback function you pass to `setTimeout`. It is pointless there.